# RestSharp JSON serialization

Tags: json, restsharp

I am building .net client REST application using RestSharp and I need to post some data to the server using JSON format (the server app can only accept JSON). The JSON format is as below:

`{
    "username": "username",
    "address": {
        "address1": "address1",
        "address2": "address2",
        "town": "Town",
        "county": "County",
        "postCode": "postcode",
        "country": "United Kingdom"
    }
    ,
    "contact": {
        "telephone": "1234",
        "fax": "12345",
        "email": "testemail@test.co.uk"

     } 
}`

I need to add the data above as parameters to the request object like below:

`request.AddBody(new { username = "username" });`

The line above will use JSON serializer to create a JSON string and it works fine but I am not sure how to create next levels (address, contact)... All address details and contact details need be embedded in the address and contact elements. Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

```
request.AddBody(new { username = "username", 
address: new { address1: "address1", address2: address2, "town": Town, county: "County", postCode: "postcode", country: United Kingdom } , 
contact: new { telephone: "1234", fax: "12345", email: "testemail@test.co.uk" });
```

?

If you know the accepted format, that should generate the required json.

If you run Fiddler http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/ as you make the request you can see what format your json is in after the rest sharp json serialiser kicks in (usually json.net which should take the above) and hopefully see where it going wrong

Comment: This is definitely the easiest way to get around RestSharp JSON serialization issues if you don't want to write a custom serializer.